# Decidability...........

Tags: logic

I'm confused about what my book is saying here. It's a bit long so I have an image of it here (if that's okay?)

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ssy3P06dqSAhREuRbr9PNj6CYYe4_HdcITg1X4kx8PM/edit

Now about the algorithm. Isn't the idea of the algorithm to decide which formulas are theorems of Γ?

I'm fine with checking to see if A is a logical axiom - in that case it can be derived from Γ. I'm fine with seeing if A is in Γ for the same reason. But the next part I don't get. I don't get what relation arbitrary A1...An is supposed to have to Γ or the theorems of Γ. Also we're supposed to check to see what formulas can be derived from Γ right? Why doesn't it mention this?

I have a feeling I'm really off with my understanding of what's going on here...

Answer (score 1):

Those $A_{k}$ are steps of the proof. The algorithm do not prove for you, it only check to see if the proof of $A_{n}$ is correct.